# MYSQL select max value if quantity is greater

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following data:

```
product_id         qty       price_reduction
     1               1              5
     1               2              10
     1               3              15
```

How can I get maximum price reduction (-15) if qty is greater than 3.
For now I use this query, which doesn't do what I want it to do for obvious reasons:

```
SELECT price_reduction 
  FROM table
 WHERE product_id = 1
   AND qty = '$qty' 
 LIMIT 1
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This isn't a representative data set.

Comment: Eh, I'm just trying to figure out if there is a way to select max value if there is matching id but qty is greater than existing with one query.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to get a single result, then filtering the results to only those `<= :qty`, ordering by `qty DESC`, and limiting the result to one should work.

```
SELECT price_reduction
FROM table
WHERE product_id = 1
AND qty <= :qty
ORDER BY qty DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Here's a working [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9aeffc/4).

Comment: @Devon, are you sure? If the quantity was 2, it should return `10`, not `15`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  I had the qty flipped in my head.

Comment: I think I did too when I posted my initial answer.

Comment: Hm, now it selects the minimum found  price_reduction value, no matter what qty I enter.

Comment: I wrote the query on the basis that the user had to have at least the specified quantity to attain the price reduction. If a user has `qty = 2` , what should the price reduction be? `10` or `15`?

Comment: Price reduction should be according to the table, but if qty is greater than maximum found value (i.e. 3). then reduction should be equal to qty=3.

Comment: @Gremlin - understood. I've updated my answer and included a working SQL Fiddle. It now does as you say.

Comment: @Devon - I think we both had the right idea the first time after all.

Comment: @Gremlin - awesome. Glad to help.